# Cannot update alignment in google spreadsheets api, Unknown name "fields", python, how to fix?

Tags: python, google-api, google-sheets-api

Try to put data, and update it alignment, but got that error.

> 'field': 'data[81]', 'description': 'Invalid JSON payload received.
> Unknown name "fields" at 'data[81]': Cannot find field.'

```
data = {
    "range": range_query,
    "values": range_query_body,
    "cell": {
        "userEnteredFormat": {
            "horizontalAlignment": "CENTER",
            "verticalAlignment": "MIDDLE",
        }
    },
    "fields": 'userEnteredFormat',

}
value_input_option = "RAW"
    
body = {
    'valueInputOption': value_input_option,
    'data': data
}


result = self.SHEET.values().batchUpdate(
spreadsheetId=spreadsheet_id, body=body).execute()
```

If remove cell, and field, it work.

Comment: Thank you for replying. I deeply apologize for `you code hard to read`. This is due to my poor skill. I think that I have to study more. And when I could modify the script to more simple script, I would like to propose it again. So in the current stage, I would like to delete my answer, because I don't want to confuse other users. I deeply apologize for this again.

Comment: What exactly do you want to align? The position of values in cells?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Do not confuse the methods [spreadsheets.batchUpdate](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets/batchUpdate) and [spreadsheets.values.batchUpdate](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets.values/batchUpdate)

- In your code you are trying to use the method `spreadsheets.values.batchUpdate` - this method only allows you to modify values, not the formatting!

- Also, `spreadsheets.values.batchUpdate` does not accept the parameter `fields` (hence your error), nor `cell`

- `horizontalAlignment` and `verticalAlignment` are properties belonging to [CellFormat](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets/cells#cellformat) which in its turn is a nested property of [cells](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets/cells)
- Consequently, to change the alignment, you need to perform the request [UpdateCells](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets/request#updatecellsrequest), which is a valid request for the method `spreadsheets.batchUpdate` - NOT `spreadsheets.values.batchUpdate`
- If you want to insert values AND format their alignment - you need to perform two different requests, luckily `spreadsheets.batchUpdate` allows you to perform several requests in one call
- In your specific case you can even update both the cell format and cell values within the single request `updateCells`
- You need to implement it as shown by Tanaike (make sure that you apply it to a spreadsheet object, not a sheet object) - his code is not hard to read, there is no way to implement it in a simplier manner.

### In order to get a better understanding

- Familiarize yourself with the [cells resource](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets/cells)
- Familiarize yourself with the available [requests](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets/request) for `spreadsheets.values.batchUpdate`
- Use the [Try this API](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets/batchUpdate) feature that allows you easy testing from the UI by chosing allowed request body properties from a dropdown menu - with the correct syntax and nesting
- Once you succesfully elaborate you request in the `Try this API` - you will gian an understanding of the request body structure and can easily implement it into your code.

[image]